# Implementing VOIP calling in android

Tags: android, sip, voip, voip-android

There are two applications that I'm building. I need to implement calling from one application to another. How can I implement that ?

Basically, user on app1 should be able to call user on app2. It's like how UBER customers can call UBER driver app using internet.
I'm using firebase as a BaaS.

Please mention links to relevant articles and tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest [Jitsi.org](https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/dev-guide/dev-guide-android-sdk). It has a great API (simple VoIP and Video call can be achieved with just a couple of lines). It's open source and you can host your own private Jitsi server if required.

If you want the SDK to handle incoming calls etc. I'd suggest [Vonage](https://tokbox.com/developer/tutorials/android/basic-video-chat/) (TokBox) or [QuickBlox](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk).

Comment: Will it possible to implement calling from one app to another?

Comment: I'm not sure regarding out-of-the-box. But you can send push notification to the callee, containing buttons to answer and decline call. Answer button could navigate you to the voice or video chat.

Comment: Actually, that's one of the primary requirements. So, I need a solution which implements that. Any other alternatives?

Comment: I've updated the answer based on my research a couple of month ago.